# How to use same RESTFUL name/route with same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the models Dad, Mom and Kid. I'm already using the kid's `index` action for Dad and made another action in the Kids controller called `mom_index` for Mom's since a kid belongs to a mom and a dad.

Right now the Dad's route goes to:

```
dad_kids GET    /dads/:dad_id/kids(.:format)      kids#index
```

Because of:

```
resources :dads do
  resources :kids
end
```

I need my Mom's route to go to:

```
mom_kids GET    /moms/:mom_id/kids(.:format)      kids#mom_index
```

But doing this:

```
resources :moms do
  resources :kids
end
```

Uses the kid's index action which is already being used by the dad. How can I get it to do this using the Kids `mom_index` action instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use an `if` statement to check whether the request is for `dads` or `moms` etc:

```
#app/controllers/kids_controller.rb
Class KidsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if params[:mom_id].present?
          # mom logic
      elsif params[:dad_id].present?
          #dad logic
      end
   end
end
```

An alternative would be to set different controllers (however this is not recommended as it's not DRY):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :moms do
   resources :moms_kids, as: "kids" #-> domain.com/moms/:mom_id/kids
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are better off either having the `kids` controller know how to deal with being used by either the dads or moms namespace or making two separate resources called `dads_kids` and `moms_kids`.

So for the first option you would leave what you have as far as routes but make the kids controller action smarter/overloaded.

For the second option you would do:

```
resources :dads do
  resources :dads_kids
end

resources :moms do
  resources :moms_kids
end
```

Then you would have 2 controllers `dads_kids_controller.rb` and `moms_kids_controller.rb`.